# How to make a discord bot loop audio? [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a bot play a piece of audio and, when the audio finishes, it will replay the audio.

What I have:

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx):
await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
if channel:
    print(channel.id)
    await channel.connect()
guild = ctx.guild
audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('audio.mp3')
voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=guild)
if not voice_client.is_playing():
    voice_client.play(audio_source, after=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`discord.VoiceClient.Play()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=play#discord.VoiceClient.play) has an `after` parameter that is called when the audio stream ends. Normally, it should be used to display error messages but you can use it to repeat the song like so:

```py
@client.command()
async def play(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    def repeat(guild, voice, audio):
        voice.play(audio, after=lambda e: repeat(guild, voice, audio))
        voice.is_playing()

    if channel and not voice.is_playing():
        audio = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('audio.mp3')
        voice.play(audio, after=lambda e: repeat(ctx.guild, voice, audio))
        voice.is_playing()
```

Comment: The method repeat() calls itself. Wouldn't this lead to infinite recursion with the stack growing with every call. Is this a good way? Is there anything that would do the same in a iterative manner?

Comment: If you don't want it to be infinite, you just have to delete `after=lambda e: repeat(ctx)` in the `repeat`  function. He wanted to audio to play again when it finishes so that's why I made it infinite

Comment: i tried using after, though without lambda. However i notice that the first instance of the song only starts playing after the `after method` has finished running. I was under the impression that the `after method` will be called after the current song finishes playing.

Comment: That's what the after argument does. It takes a callable as value and this value will be called when a video is over.

Comment: But in all my testing the `after method` for me does not wait for song finished. Instead it executes right before the song has even started

Comment: I've never had this problem so I can't help you :/

Comment: I doubt this solution is efficient. Every time sounds is going to play, you have to load `audio.mp3` instead of loading them into memory and use it over and over.

Comment: I wasn't really experienced into music bots 2 mounths ago and that was my solution. Now, it should be more efficient :) @Fusion