# Discord.py Looping an audio source

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py, ffmpeg-python

Does anyone know how to loop the same source in FFmpeg?

This is my code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):

if (ctx.author.voice):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = await channel.connect()
    source = FFmpegPCMAudio('test.mp3')
    player = voice.play(source)
else:
    await ctx.send('You need to be in a Voice-Channel.')
```

I want the audio-file "test.mp3" looped permanently. I've searched on the internet but all the results given there were outdated.

Comment: Maybe you can find answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457834/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-loop-audio-discord-py)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to know when a song has finished playing.

```
if (ctx.author.voice):
    finished = False 
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = await channel.connect()

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: finished = True)
```

Using the lambda function you can implement a loop structure to replay the song once finished.

Comment: what is e?
`after=lambda e:`

Comment: @Toma That would be a bound variable/argument to the lambda function. I believe it should work with any other variable letter

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I'm currently using for myself:

```py
async def play_source(voice_client):
    source = FFmpegPCMAudio("test.mp3")
    voice_client.play(source, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else bot.loop.create_task(play_source(voice_client)))
```

This solution is just a basic one. After the source is completed, it starts again with the same voice_client.

If the audio starts to speed up at the beginning then just put a `await asyncio.sleep(0.5)` between the source and the voice_client.play.

To start it in the first place, just replace your code like this:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):

if (ctx.author.voice):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = await channel.connect()
    bot.loop.create_task(play_source(voice))
else:
    await ctx.send('You need to be in a Voice-Channel.')
```