# How do i loop music in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

How do i loop music in discord.py?
my current code is:

> ```
> TOKEN = 'my token that im not gonna share here :D'
>
> import discord
> from discord.ext import commands
> import youtube_dl
> import os
> import nacl
>
> client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*")
>
> @client.event
> async def on_ready():
>     print('ready')
>
> @client.command()
> async def join(ctx):
>     voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name='music custombot')
>     await voiceChannel.connect()
>
> @client.command()
> async def play(ctx, url : str):
>     song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
>     if song_there:
>      os.remove('song.mp3')
>
>     voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
>
>     ydl_opts = {
>         'format': 'bestaudio/best',
>         'postprocessors': [{
>             'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
>             'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
>             'preferredquality': '192',
>         }],
>     }
>     with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
>         ydl.download([url])
>     for file in os.listdir("./"):
>         if file.endswith(".mp3"):
>             os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
>     voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
>
> client.run(TOKEN)
> ```

I want to loop only 1 song, not a queue with songs in, However i have no clue how to do this.
I have searched on stackoverflow/youtube for similar questions, however i could not find anything.
Can anybody provide me with code please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a discord bot loop audio? \[discord.py\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457834/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-loop-audio-discord-py)

Comment: It doesn't, I'm not sure why but the code just doesn't work. No errors, Just doesn't loop. Have tried to change code.